# Time complexity of this bipartite matching algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity, matching, bipartite

I was looking at some different ways to do bipartite matching and found this 
implementation http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/, am wondering what the time complexity for it is? Most things I've read seem to do bipartite matchings in polynomial time, but  this seems exponential?

Comment: It's polynomial, your article from geeksforgeeks contains a link to Ford-Fulkerson algorithm description where its run time is discussed.

Comment: Yes but that is for a maximum flow of any graph, I was thinking that it would be different if we know that we are looking at a bipartite graph?

Comment: If it's polynomial for any graph it can't be worse for a particular case. Can it be (still polynomial but) better for this particular case - that's another question.